# In machine learning, should I remove original features after a feature combination?

Tags: machine-learning, data-analysis, data-preprocessing

If I made a new feature (c) using two existing features (a,b) like c = a*b or a+b, should I remove the two originals? (to avoid the duplication problem?) Please, help me bro..

Answer (score 0):

If you use a linear combination of features with the original features your feature matrix becomes singular. Therefore, the original features should be removed from the data set.

Comment: Now I see, a linear combination would make a high correlation between the new and the existing features. Thanks, I got a insight.